# decode PHP JSON

Tags: php, json

My php receives a JSON string similar to this:

```
{"one-value":"GOOGLE","sub-values":{"sub thing":"xpto"}}
```

How do I get the value of "sub thing" ?

If I want "one-value":

```
$json = json_decode($data);
$service = $json->{'one-value'};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$json = json_decode(
  '{"one-value":"GOOGLE","sub-values":{"sub thing":"xpto"}}'
);

echo $json->{'sub-values'}->{'sub thing'};

// OR
$json = json_decode(
  '{"one-value":"GOOGLE","sub-values":{"sub thing":"xpto"}}',
  TRUE
);

echo $json['sub-values']['sub thing'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
json_decode($data,true);
```

will give you a complete indexed array of all valueson the JSON, after that you can do

```
$json["sub-values"]["sub thing"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = json_decode($data,true); 
$service = $json["sub-values"]['one-value'];
```

'true' is used to convert json string into associative array